# Hibernate optimistic locking for SQL native queries

Tags: java, hibernate

Does hibernate support optimistic locking with explicit version concept for SQL native queries?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can construct a native SQL query, obtaining a `SQLQuery` instance from the session. Use `addEntity` to tell hibernate the type of entity that is returned by the query. Hibernate will properly manage these entity instances that are returned.

The other aspect that you need to be aware of is caching. Hibernate does not understand the native query, so it does not know which tables are being accessed. This means that hibernate cannot auto-flush the caches to ensure that the query sees the current state of the database. This leads to incorrect results that may be subtle and hard to identify.

The fix for the caching/flushing issue is to tell the `SQLQuery` instance which entity types are accessed. Use the `addSynchronized*` methods to tell hibernate what is going on in the query, and hibernate will do all the hard work.

Comment: Query deleteQuery = session.createQuery("DELETE FROM XYZ WHERE COL = :value"); In this case, how hibernate verify VERSION before deleting the records?

Comment: Optimistic locking is not an issue for this query. The version information is used to ensure that when you do an update that nobody else has updated the row in the meantime. You still need to tell hibernate that you have done something to table XYZ if you want caching to work properly.

Comment: Just set the hibernate.show_sql to true and run the native query,  you'll see if the version field is updated or not.